# Достать текст из програмно созданных TextView и EditText

Tags: java, android

У меня в в отдельном методе программно создаются `TextView` и `EditText`:

```
for (int i=0; i<objArr.length(); i++) {
    TextView txt_view = new TextView(this);
    EditText txt_edit = new EditText(this);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlayout2);
    layout.addView(txt_view);
    layout.addView(txt_edit);
}
```

Их может быть разное количество, в зависимости от массива `objArr`.
В другом методе при нажатии кнопки мне надо вытащить весь текст из этих созданных элементов. Подскажите как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно по разному:

1. Пройтись циклом по всем детям `LinearLayout`, скастовать их к `TextView` и получить содержимое вызовом `getText()`

   ```
   ArrayList<String> allTextViewAndEditTextContent = new ArrayList<>();
   for(int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++)
   {
       TextView tv = ( TextView ) layout.getChildAt(i);
       String textInTv = tv.getText(); //вот он, искомый текст.
       allTextViewAndEditTextContent.add(textInTv);
   }
   //теперь весь текст из всех добавленных ранее элементов хранится
   // в переменной allTextViewAndEditTextContent, имеющей длину,
   //равную кол-ву добавленных в layout элементов
   ```
2. Ещё можно поместить созданные `TextView` и `EditText` в `ArrayList<TextView>` (общий или раздельные) и после добавления в `LinearLayout` и назначения им содержимого надо циклом опять таки по ним пробежаться:

   ```
   ArrayList<TextView> listOfTextOrEditTextViews = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i=0; i<objArr.length(); i++) {
       TextView txt_view = new TextView(this);
       listOfTextOrEditTextViews.add(txt_view);
       EditText txt_edit = new EditText(this);
       listOfTextOrEditTextViews.add(txt_edit);
       LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linlayout2);
       layout.addView(txt_view);
       layout.addView(txt_edit);
   }
   //присваиваем им содержимое...

   //и теперь циклом вытаскиваем:
   ArrayList<String> allTextViewAndEditTextContent = new ArrayList<>();
   for (int i = 0; i < listOfTextOrEditTextViews.size(); i++)
   {
       allTextViewAndEditTextContent.add(listOfTextOrEditTextViews.get(i).getText());
   }
   ```
3. Присвоить каждому создаваемому `View` `ID` и искать по ним в `layout`. Этот метод хуже, т.к. вы не сможете гарантировать уникальность `ID` и их список надо ещё где-то хранить. Но так тоже можно.

Comment: спасобо за наводку. Уже сделал:
 List<EditText> edits = new ArrayList<EditText>();
и в методе создания EditText:
edits.add(txt_edit);
Потом просто:
for (int i = 0; i<edits.size(); i++){
             editContent = edits_name.get(i).getText();
        }

Comment: @YuraHalych оформите свое решение отдельным ответом, так как оно отличается от предложенных

Comment: @pavlofff, добавил в свой ответ

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так:

Сперва обьявил ArrayList для EditText

```
List<EditText> edits = new ArrayList<EditText>();
```

Потом в методе, в котором создаются EditText добавил строчку

```
edits.add(txt_edit);
```

чтобы добавить их в ArrayList.

В методе, где нужно вытащить текст из EditText просто прошелся по ArrayList циклом:

```
String editData;
for (int i = 0; i<edits.size(); i++) {                    
     editData = edits.get(i).getText().toString(); //Содержимое EditText
     //тут уже что-то делаем
     }
```